# Is bitnami nginx-ingress-controller support canary?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, bitnami, k3s

I have been searching on their official pages, and most of their documentation refers to kubernetes/nginx-ingress [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/). In Kubernetes-nginx-ingress support canary development.

and i tried to implement what i read to activate the canary simply
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"`
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: "50"`

but it did not work, it showed a "404" page not found. If the fact that the bitnami nginx-ingress does not support canary deployment, how could I change or import/update my helm bitnami-nginx-ingress to kubernetes-nginx-ingress without losing any important configuration? which is the safest way to do it.